# Pentaho error Required subelement 'user'

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I get a error when I try to preview the query: 
I get this error :
ParentException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required subelement 'user'
    at org.osjava.sj.loader.convert.DataSourceConverter.convert(DataSourceConverter.java:54)
    at org.osjava.sj.loader.JndiLoader.convert(JndiLoader.java:351)

can anyone help me ?

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide enough information so that we understand your request. Are you using Kettle from your Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2):

make sure there are no empty spaces in the jdbc.properties file of pdi after "=".  I had the same issue, I removed the empty spaces and it worked. ex: 
`test1/user=root
test1/password=Letmein1234
test1/url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following properties to the jdbc.properties file located in data-integration/simple-jndi directory

[JNDI_connection_Name]/user=

[JNDI_connection_Name]/password=

Answer (score 0):

These attributes are mandatory:

```
JNDI_connection_Name/user=

JNDI_connection_Name/password=
```

even if they are empty (e.g. for SQLite file).
No '*user*' in one section cause problems in all sections.